Restriction of an almost-complex structure to a complex structure on a sub-manifold?
I have been thinking about this recent question of mine a bit more and came to the following question: Consider a manifold $M$ endowed with a non-integrable almost complex structure $J$. Can it happen that $M$ has a sub-manifold $N$ such that $J$ restricts to an almost-complex structure on $N$ that is integrable? If the answer is yes, then what is an example?

Take the product space of any non-integrable almost complex manifold and a complex manifold. The restriction to the product of a point and the complex manifold gives you a counter example.

@Rei Henigman: good point! But I guess this is an example not a counter-example :)

I'm not sure why I was being so negative ;)

Actually, any almost complex manifold $M$  has lots of almost complex submanifolds of real dimension $2$, and the almost complex structure on $M$  restricts to all of these 'pseudoholmorphic curves'  to be integrable.

It can happen, though, that there are no almost complex submanifolds of $M$ of dimension higher than 2 until you get to $M$ itself.  For example, the $\mathrm{G}_2$-invariant almost complex structure on $S^6$ has no almost complex submanifolds of dimension $4$.
